# Einstein Web recommendation - Custom scenarios

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations, einstein-next-best-action

I have a following use case:

Customer wants to send 3 different emails and recommend 3 different products on the web to the customer:

1. Products that are regularly bought
2. Product that user did not buy in the last 6 months
3. Product that user did not buy ever, but has the highest value

For #1 I believe I can use one of the Site Data scenarios like Top Sellers. However, I am not sure how to implement #2 and #3.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

These are the different scenarios you can choose from: '[Einstein Recommendation Scenarios](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_recommendation_scenarios.htm&type=5)'

Items the profile has already purchased will be excluded from recommendations regardless of the time frame.

There is not a process to create a custom scenario but you can use [rule manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_personalization_rule_manager.htm&type=5) to 'tweak' a scenario.

Comment: Thanks I am aware of what you have posted (links).However, I am not sure how I would tweak the scenario (and which exactly) to resolve scenario #2 and #3.                                                              Basically, what you are saying is that we are already recommending products customer did not buy and within the rule manager we can tweak them to recommend 'not bought products' with the highest value or 'not bought' products in the last 6 months. Did I understand you correctly?